# Django-taggit. How to add a tag to all the items in a category

Tags: django, tags, categories

I'd like to have the ability to add the same tag to all the items within a category.

Let's say I have a category named Service and Service has 42 posts.  I would like to be able to add a tag named "tire" for instance to every post in Service

From admin, perhaps, how could this be done?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Through the django shell? In a data migration? Or with a view?

Comment: You can use the .update on a queryset to update all objects in that queryset.

Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2007).update(headline='Everything is the same')

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

Comment: Can you share the relevant models?